Vulkan+glm orthographic projection clipping unexpectedly
I am following along https://vulkan-tutorial.com/ and just finished the chapter on Uniform Buffers. I tried to change the projection matrix to see the outcome, however, when I change the zFar value in glm::ortho, it clips unexpectedly.

When zFar is lesser than the first vertex, nothing shows as expected
When zFar is more than the first vertex, the quad starts showing up, as expected
However, as zFar increases, the quad starts clipping, from the bottom up!

I checked by altering zFar in the call to glm::perspective as well, the behaviour does not occur. Here is the code:
void updateUniformBuffer(uint32_t currentImage){
        static auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto currentTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        float time = std::chrono::duration<float, std::chrono::seconds::period>(currentTime - startTime).count();

        UniformBufferObject ubo{};
        ubo.model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        ubo.view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

        // ubo.proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), swapChainExtent.width / (float) swapChainExtent.height, 0.1f, time/1.0f);

        float aspectRatio = swapChainExtent.width / (float) swapChainExtent.height;
        ubo.proj = glm::ortho(2.0f*-aspectRatio, 2.0f*aspectRatio, -2.0f, 2.0f, -1.0f, time/1.0f);
        ubo.proj[1][1] *= -1;

        memcpy(uniformBuffersMapped[currentImage], &ubo, sizeof(ubo));
    }

Please help me out here, sorry if a similar question has been answered before, but my search came up empty ;-;

I had the same issue bit ago.
Short answer -
you need to include
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE before you import glm.
Long Answer -
In the tutorial series, we set
viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;

Unless you include the macro, when you create a glm::ortho(2.0f*-aspectRatio, 2.0f*aspectRatio, -2.0f, 2.0f, -1.0f, time/1.0f), the constructor defined in glm\ext\matrix_clip_space.inl as -
    template<typename T>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> ortho(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T zNear, T zFar)
    {
#       if GLM_CONFIG_CLIP_CONTROL == GLM_CLIP_CONTROL_LH_ZO
            return orthoLH_ZO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
#       elif GLM_CONFIG_CLIP_CONTROL == GLM_CLIP_CONTROL_LH_NO
            return orthoLH_NO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
#       elif GLM_CONFIG_CLIP_CONTROL == GLM_CLIP_CONTROL_RH_ZO
            return orthoRH_ZO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
#       elif GLM_CONFIG_CLIP_CONTROL == GLM_CLIP_CONTROL_RH_NO
            return orthoRH_NO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
#       endif
    }

is called and it will choose the last branch, GLM_CLIP_CONTROL_RH_NO. Here, the difference between NO and ZO is:

ZO (Zero to One): Depth values are normalized between 0 and 1.
NO (Negative One to One): Depth values are normalized between -1 and 1.

Since the minDepth is set to 0.0f, clearly, we need the values to be normalized between 0 and 1, so we need to switch to ZO. To do that, we need to define the GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE  macro, which, as it suggests, forces GLM to normalize the depth between 0 and 1.
Alternatively, you can also change viewport.minDepth to -1 but if you set up the validation layers correctly, they'll scream at you that you need to enable an extension to do that. I did not delve that deep into it, but you could try.
